# Constructor object always return a function not a string

Tags: javascript, node.js

I do have this kind problem below that create a new constructor and must return a string in an object. My data is an object array like this

`val _List = [{name: 'name1', number: 2, 'message': 'Hello World'},{name: 'name1', number: 2, 'message': 'Good bye'}]`

And the code will be executed by a test

```
test2 = new ProgramDevice('2');

it('should send string exactly', function() {
    expect(test2.postStringReturn).toEqual('Hello world!');
}
```

The solution that I created is something like below but instead of string return it returns a function

```
this.postStringReturn= _List.find(data => {
    if(data.number == this.number ) {
      return data.message
    }
  });
```

Can someone explain where I did wrong? Sorry not really good at OOP, just someone tell me where is my mistake

Update //

If I create something like this

```
var ProgramDevice = function (num) { // i.e. '192.168.0.1'
  this.number= num;
}

ProgramDevice.prototype = {
   postStringReturn = _List.find(data => { data.number == this.number }).message
}
```

How can I get the `this.number` in using prototype

Comment: Have you run it first before running the test?

Comment: @Kholio yes, it should return a string and to return the message the same as HelloWorld im doing find function array to track the number, unfortunately my object returns a output like this Function[anonymouse()] I suspect that it is not correctly returning the data since postStringReturn calls as an object

Comment: @Kholio the things is how can I return the message if the data was stored on the object array and can be accessed using the number provided by the constructor

Comment: find doesn't return what you return in callback, it returns the item in the array that meets the condition.   IOW: find will return the array item, so it will be there you want to get the message..  eg.  `this.postStringReturn= _List.find(data => data.number == this.number).message;`

Comment: @Keith I inserted your suggested code but it is not getting the message as it is undefined

Comment: @nyx97  That would mean the find is finding nothing.   But you not using the prototype correctly anyway..  You maybe meant to do ->  `ProgramDevice.prototype.postStringReturn = function () { return _List.find(data => { data.number == this.number }).message; }};`

Comment: @Keith I just inserted your code, you can view the code here https://repl.it/repls/SnowValidDoom

Answer (score 1):

Well, try to replace `this.number` (only to evaluate this situation) with the digit `2`, it should then return 'hello world' and 'Good Bye'. If this is the case, you might have some reference error.

Also the test might be failing because your initial array has `2` as a value of the property `number` in both the elements, that will not return what the test expected. It will return the other value 'Good bye' as well, and for testing this is a fail. Got my point?

Comment: The test good, but I think the error is from the reference, I dont know how to deal with object that getting an constructor data

Comment: Can you share the original code, I'd need to trace your reference first.

Comment: here is the link https://repl.it/repls/SnowValidDoom it always returns a function